# Search by column name and the row values

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the first column is a number of days, all the rest columns represent the interest rate for a specific date. So, my table looks somewhat like this:

```
 1. days   02/01/2008   03/01/2008   04/01/2008
 2. 7      4.76         5.87         4.36
```

I need to search for an interesting rate for a specific date for a certain number of days, let's say i need a rate on 08/01/2010 for 360 days. How can I do that? (All the information I need to find is already in the table, so there is no need for extra calculations)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't quite get your database design - are you saying your days column can contain an unknown collection of dates and you rates have a column each?

Comment: With this table structure you need to dynamically generate the sql statement or each query since you have to know which columns you ant to query. I would unpivot this table into days - date - rate structure. After that this query is really simple. If you are not willing to do this, then you are stuck with a complicated solutions.

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
I think the idea of unpivoting is ideal but I checked the syntax for the UNPIVOT command and i have a new question then. Is it necessary to state each column name in the command? I have dates for three years there which would be pretty tiring to name  each single column in the code.

Comment: My days column has values from 7 to 3600 and there is a rate for each specific date for each certain period. For example, there is a rate for 05/09/2009 for 187 days.